# I can't access ng-repeat items inside directive

Tags: angular, angular-google-maps

I have an issue with Angular. I've only recently started using Angular so I dont know everything there is to know yet. I'm using *AGM* ***(Angular Google Maps)*** and I'm trying to add markers to the map as follows:

```
<agm-map> ... </agm-map>
```

inside:

```
<agm-marker [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng"></agm-marker>
```

this works. However, when I try to dynamically add the markers from a data list in my component.ts, it says can't read ... from undefined.

```
<agm-marker *ngFor="let item in data" [latitude]="item.point_lat" [longitude]="item.point_lng"></agm-marker>
```

I'm guessing that **item** can not be accessed like this yet. But I can't figure out how it should..

EDIT: When I run this, the data shows up like expected.

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of data">
    <th>{{item.point_lat}}</th> //51.34454736511800 
    <td>{{item.point_lng}}</td> //4.32184512840880
</tr>
```

Comment: Are you using AngularJS (1.x) or Angular (2+). If you are using Angular (2+) you have to use the NgFor syntax https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ngforof

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm using Angular4. When I change ng-repeat to *ngFor, nothing changes. It still won't show any markers.

Comment: You are using `<agm-marker *ngFor="let item of data" [latitude]="item.point_lat" [longitude]="item.point_lng"></agm-marker>` now?

Comment: Yes that's what I'm using. I'm no longer getting the ... is undefined error. But the markers simply won't show up.

Comment: And you have a variable in your component called **data** that is an array with the data?

Comment: Correct, the **data** is filled as I can get item.point_lat as interpolation

Comment: Could you post the whole excerpt from the template and the component?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/RqcaYEam5G6qopZzYPl0
3 classes I use, 
**maps.component.ts**, 
**maps.component.html**, 
**politiekantoren.service.ts**

Comment: After some investiagtion I found the issue. The lat and lng values are supplied as strings and the component requires them to be numbers. You need to convert the string to number.

Comment: I have changed the type in the interface from **string** to **number**, but without result

Comment: `<agm-marker *ngFor="let item of data" [latitude]="Number(item.point_lat)" [longitude]="Number(item.point_lng)"></agm-marker>` Just changing the type does not work, you have to cast the variables.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162591/discussion-between-melvin-and-shadowlauch).

Comment: I moved @Shadowlauch and OP solution to a community wiki answer. Feel free to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

*Solution by Shadowlauch and OP.*

*item.point_lat* & *item.point_lng* are **strings**. While *`<agm-marker>`* expects numbers. I wrote a function in component.ts

```
stringToNumber(val: number) {
    return Number(val);
}
```

and converted the string to number like:

```
<agm-marker *ngFor="let item of data" [latitude]="stringToNumber(item.point_lat)" [longitude]="stringToNumber(item.point_lng)"></agm-marker>
```